# Where truffle save the compiled contract

Tags: truffle, solc

I'm trying to find where truffle store the compiled code. I'd like to take this bytecode and to deploy it manually with MyEtherWallet

Answer (score 3):

Truffle will save the compiled contract(s) in < project_name >**/build/contracts** folder.

If you aren't using Truffle to deploy / [migrate](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/migrations) the contracts as well as compile them, then a more lightweight approach would be just to use the Solidity compiler, command line tool, [solc](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/using-the-compiler.html).

*Note:* it is possible to deploy contracts to a network without running an Ethereum full node, via Truffle, by using [Infura instead. The details of which are documented on Truffle's website](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider).